# Is it possible to specify an offset for JSON.NET deserialization of DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, json.net, datetimeoffset

The following statement prints "1/1/0001 4:00:00 PM -05:00"

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>("\"0001-01-01T16:00:00\""));
```

This is because when json.net deserializes a DateTime string (which doesn't have an offset) to a DateTimeOffset object, it assigns the local offset, which in this case is -05:00.

What if I don't want to use the local offset? Is there any way I can specify an offset to use for this deserialization?

(The use case is the database server and the web server are in different time zones, and I need the incoming requests that have zone-unspecified time to have the database server's offset after deserialization.)

Update: I can't control the incoming time string's format. I have a data transfer object class which has a DateTimeOffset property and I need to store the incoming time data to this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type you're deserializing into should match the data you are expecting.  If you're not expecting an offset to be included, then don't deserialize into a `DateTimeOffset`.  Instead, deserialize to a `DateTime`.  It will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` for its `.Kind` property.

The knowledge you have about the web server's time zone is extraneous to the task of deserialization.  So apply it separately, after-the-fact.

```
// deserialize the json
DateTime dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"2014-01-01T00:00:00\"");

// find your target time zone
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

// apply the time zone to determine the offset, and create the DateTimeOffset
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, tz.GetUtcOffset(dt));
```

**Update**

Per comments, if you need to do this conversion in the manner you've requested, you'll need a custom json converter.  This should do the trick:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    private readonly string defaultTimeZoneId;

    public CustomDateTimeConverter(string defaultTimeZoneId)
    {
        this.defaultTimeZoneId = defaultTimeZoneId;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType != typeof (DateTimeOffset) && objectType != typeof (DateTimeOffset?))
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

        var dateText = reader.Value.ToString();
        if (objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset?) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateText))
            return null;

        if (dateText.IndexOfAny(new[] { 'Z', 'z', '+'}) == -1 && dateText.Count(c => c == '-') == 2)
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Parse(dateText);
            var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(this.defaultTimeZoneId);
            var offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
            return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
        }

        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateText);
    }
}
```

Then you can wire it up during conversion:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
settings.Converters.Add(new CustomDateTimeConverter(defaultTimeZoneId: "Eastern Standard Time"));
DateTimeOffset dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>("\"2014-01-01T00:00:00\"", settings);
```

Be sure to used a valid time zone id.  Do not use a fixed offset.

Also, this will not be the correct approach if you are trying to pass a time without a date.  That is a completely different problem, and passing in `0001-01-01` for the date is not a great approach.  I'll be happy to discuss with you [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50244/datetime).

Comment: Well, the problem is, we have to support both types of time, zone-unspecified and zone-specific, with a DateTimeOffset property.

Comment: And I can't correct the deserialized DateTimeOffset object, because I can't tell whether the object came in with an offset and therefore needs no correction, or it came in without an offset and was assigned the local offset.

Comment: Is that part of your data contract - that you'll support ambiguous input data?  If so, I don't see how you'd easily resolve it.

Comment: Keep in mind also that an input date and time without an offset is not the same as a unique point in time.  It could be ambiguous due to [daylight saving time issues](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Comment: One approach you could consider is to write your own `JsonConvert` class.

Comment: Also, why passing `0001-01-01`? are you actually just trying to pass a time without a date?

Comment: Yes, there's a DTO with a time-only property. I was hoping I don't have to write my own Json.Convert. DST is a whole other beast I have yet to tackle. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Matt, turns out there's a problem with your solution. It works for json strings that don't contain an offset, but not for the ones that do... I've added the details in chat. I hope you have a moment to look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the offset in the original string (-8:00):

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>("\"0001-01-01T16:00:00-08:00\""));
```

If not, try this

```
var dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"0001-01-01T16:00:00\"");
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(-8));
```

Comment: I can't control the incoming time string. Sorry, I will add clarification.

Comment: Try adding the offset manually after parsing into `DateTime`.

Comment: I can't. As I mentioned in another comment, it's not possible to tell if the deserialized DateTimeOffset object needs correction. How would I know if the offset was added during the deserialization, as opposed to being a part of the incoming time string?

Comment: If the `Kind` property on dateTime is `Local` then it means the string contained an offset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the incoming time string contained offset, then the resulting deserialized DateTimeOffset object will have an embedded DateTime object with Kind = Unspecified. If the incoming time string did not contain an offset, then the result is still the same, the embedded DateTime object has Kind = Unspecified.

Comment: I am referring to the 2nd section in my answer. 

If the incoming string contains an offset, the deserialized `DateTime` object `Kind` property will be `Local`. Otherwise, `Kind` will contain Unspecified.  This is how you can tell whether the original Json string has an offset or not.

Comment: But the json string will be deserialized into a DateTimeOffset object, not a DateTime object. Is there anything I can use in DateTimeOffset to determine this?

Comment: To clarify, I don't have control over the deserialization target type. DateTimeOffset will be what the json string gets deserialized to.

Comment: No, I do not think so.  You have to deserialize into `DateTime` and then convert into `DateTimeOffset` like I did above.

Comment: Another way is to look at the Json string to see if it has an offset perhaps using regular expression or simple search.

Comment: I have to support both formats, one with offset, and one without offset. If I deserialize to DateTime, I will lose the offset of the json string.

Not sure if i can "look" at the json string since it would come in as a web API request and is automatically deserialized. I'll see if I can...